# Simple Product Not Showing in Configuration Tab

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

I have created a configurable product from admin panel, I used one attribute with two values, so it is working fine on frontend and both options are showing in the dropdown as expected. But the issue is, inside the configuration tab associated simple products not showing what may be the reason, I have run reindexing also.
I am using Magento 2.4.3-p1

Comment: Could you take a screenshot of the attribute in the product edit page that you mentioned?

Comment: @TuVan here it is https://imgur.com/a/Sd3qmLE

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add associated simple products to your configurable product.

Take a look at this guide to know how to create a configurable product with associated simple products: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-admin/catalog/products/types/product-create-configurable.html

Comment: If this answer works as your expected, please mark it as **accepted** and upvote the answer.

Comment: I have added simple products and it is showing on the frontend with variation but in the admin panel inside the configuration tab it is not showing, here is screenshot https://imgur.com/a/L9k5BJe

Comment: Are you sure **A** and **B** are child (simple) products?

Comment: Could you follow the guide I mentioned in the answer to creating a new configurable product?

Comment: yes I am sure A and B are child (simple) products and I have followed the guide.